# Change to total price field in not reflecting

Tags: javascript

Below are my html code and onchange(). I am not getting any error message but the changes I require in the

The html is for a shopping cart where there are columns for each product that is in the cart and the last column of each row is for the total price of the product which needs to be changed as we increase the quantity.

```js
function WO() {
  var tbody = document.getElementById("cartSection");

  for (var i = 0; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = tbody.rows[i];
    var qty = row.cells[3].childNodes[0].value;

    var price = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    var answer = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);
    row.cells[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue = answer;


  }
  document.getElementById("inputNumber").onchange = function() {
    myFunction()
  };

  function myFunction() {
    row.cells[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);
  };
};
WO();
```

```html
<div class="cart-section">
  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-xs striped-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-head">
        <th scope="col">image</th>
        <th scope="col">product name</th>
        <th scope="col">price</th>
        <th scope="col">quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">action</th>
        <th scope="col">total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cartSection">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/89/1569065085-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Black formal shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          449.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" id="inputNumber" class="form-control input-number" value="2" onchange="myFunction">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">898.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/94/1569065206-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Slim brown leather shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          800.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" id="inputNumber" class="form-control input-number" value="2" onchange="myFunction">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">1600.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/93/1569065178-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Dual Colour Formal</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          500.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" id="inputNumber" class="form-control input-number" value="2" onchange="myFunction">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">1000.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-md">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>total price :</td>
        <td>
          <h2>$6935.00</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div class="row cart-buttons">
    <div class="col-6"><a href="/site/index" class="btn btn-solid">continue shopping</a></div>
    <div class="col-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-solid">check out</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have multiple identical IDs  - that is not allowed. Use a class or delegate

Comment: Please check scope of myFunction. It is defined inside another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start. You had many issues

```js
function WO() {
  var tbody = document.getElementById("cartSection");

  for (var i = 0; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = tbody.rows[i];
    var qty = row.cells[3].childNodes[0].value;

    var price = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    var answer = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);
    row.cells[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue = answer;


  }
  document.getElementById("cartSection").addEventListener("change",function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.name==="quantity") {
      var row = tgt.closest("tr");
      var qty =  Number(tgt.value); 
      var amt =  Number(row.querySelector(".amount").innerText.trim());
      console.log(qty,amt)
      row.querySelector(".totalprice").innerText = (amt*qty).toFixed(2);

    }  
  })
};
WO();
```

```html
<div class="cart-section">
  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-xs striped-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-head">
        <th scope="col">image</th>
        <th scope="col">product name</th>
        <th scope="col">price</th>
        <th scope="col">quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">action</th>
        <th scope="col">total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cartSection">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/89/1569065085-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Black formal shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          449.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">898.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/94/1569065206-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Slim brown leather shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          800.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">1600.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/93/1569065178-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Dual Colour Formal</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          500.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice">1000.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-md">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>total price :</td>
        <td>
          <h2>$6935.00</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div class="row cart-buttons">
    <div class="col-6"><a href="/site/index" class="btn btn-solid">continue shopping</a></div>
    <div class="col-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-solid">check out</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Trigger the change on each to calculate from start. Missing here is a totalling of all

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=quantity]")].forEach(function(qty) {
    qty.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      var tgt = e.target;
      var row = tgt.closest("tr");
      var qty = Number(tgt.value);
      var amt = Number(row.querySelector(".amount").innerText.trim());
      row.querySelector(".totalprice").innerText = (amt * qty).toFixed(2);
    });
  });
  var event = new Event('change');
  // Dispatch it.
  [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=quantity]")].forEach(function(qty) {
    qty.dispatchEvent(event);
  })

})
```

```html
<div class="cart-section">
  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-xs striped-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-head">
        <th scope="col">image</th>
        <th scope="col">product name</th>
        <th scope="col">price</th>
        <th scope="col">quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">action</th>
        <th scope="col">total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cartSection">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/89/1569065085-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Black formal shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          449.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/94/1569065206-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Slim brown leather shoe</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          800.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="/web/product/93/1569065178-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Dual Colour Formal</a>

        </td>
        <td class="amount">
          500.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="2">
        </td>

        <td><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="ti-close"></i></a></td>
        <td class="totalprice"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <table class="table cart-table table-responsive-md">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>total price :</td>
        <td>
          <h2>$6935.00</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div class="row cart-buttons">
    <div class="col-6"><a href="/site/index" class="btn btn-solid">continue shopping</a></div>
    <div class="col-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-solid">check out</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```